# How to limit the no of results to just 5 per 'user' but allow for more rows if the immediate value at 5th row is same as the consecutive rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a database with Domain_id, salary and salary date of an organisation.
My question is i have to find 5 highest salaries per domain, but the no of rows (5 rows) can increase to more, if the immediate 6th,7th or more rows have the same value as the 5th row. I tried using window function.

select * from 
(SELECT id_domain, salary_value,salary_date,
  dense_rank() OVER (
    PARTITION BY id_domain
    ORDER BY salary_date DESC,salary_value desc
  ) AS comment_rank from employee)
employee where comment_rank <=5

I tried using lag and lead in this context, still couldn't figure it out

```
select * from (SELECT id_domain,salary_value, salary_value - lag(salary_value) 
OVER (
     PARTITION BY id_domain
     ORDER BY salary_value desc
) AS diff, row_number() over (partition by id_user order by salary_value desc) as rowrank
FROM employee)as t 
case when rowrank > 5
where (case when diff <> 0 then rowrank > 5 else false end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rank()`.  If you want 5+ then:

```
select *
from (select id_domain,salary_value,
             salary_value - lag(salary_value) over (partition by id_domain order by salary_value desc) AS diff,
             rank() over (partition by id_user order by salary_value desc) as rowrank
      from employee)as t 
     ) t
where rowrank < 6;
```

or:

```
where rowrank <= 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon.. I underestimated rank() :D